# Writing metadata to a pdf using pyobjc

Tags: python, cocoa, pdf, pyobjc, pdfkit

I'm trying to write metadata to a pdf file using the following python code:

```
from Foundation import *
from Quartz import *

url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_("test.pdf")
pdfdoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(url)
assert pdfdoc, "failed to create document"

print "reading pdf file"

attrs = {}
attrs[PDFDocumentTitleAttribute] = "THIS IS THE TITLE"
attrs[PDFDocumentAuthorAttribute] = "A. Author and B. Author"

PDFDocumentTitleAttribute = "test"

pdfdoc.setDocumentAttributes_(attrs)
pdfdoc.writeToFile_("mynewfile.pdf")   

print "pdf made"
```

This appears to work fine (no errors to the consoled), however when I examine the metadata of the file it is as follows:

```
PdfID0:
242b7e252f1d3fdd89b35751b3f72d3
PdfID1:
242b7e252f1d3fdd89b35751b3f72d3
NumberOfPages: 4
```

and the original file had the following metadata:

```
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Microsoft Word - PROGRESS  ON  THE  GABION  HOUSE Compressed.doc
InfoKey: Producer
InfoValue: GPL Ghostscript 8.15
InfoKey: Author
InfoValue: PWK
InfoKey: ModDate
InfoValue: D:20101021193627-05'00'
InfoKey: CreationDate
InfoValue: D:20101008152350Z
PdfID0: d5fd6d3960122ba72117db6c4d46cefa
PdfID1: 24bade63285c641b11a8248ada9f19
NumberOfPages: 4
```

So the problems are, it is not appending the metadata, and it is clearing the previous metadata structure. What do I need to do to get this to work? My objective is to append metadata that reference management systems can import.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark is on the right track, but there are a few peculiarities that should be accounted for.

First, he is correct that `pdfdoc.documentAttributes` is an `NSDictionary` that contains the document metadata. You would like to modify that, but note that `documentAttributes` gives you an `NSDictionary`, which is immutable. You have to convert it to an `NSMutableDictionary` as follows:

```
attrs = NSMutableDictionary.alloc().initWithDictionary_(pdfDoc.documentAttributes())
```

Now you can modify `attrs` as you did. There is no need to write `PDFDocument.PDFDocumentTitleAttribute` as Mark suggested, that one won't work, `PDFDocumentTitleAttribute` is declared as a module-level constant, so just do as you did in your own code.

Here is the full code that works for me:

```
from Foundation import *
from Quartz import *

url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_("test.pdf")
pdfdoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(url)

attrs = NSMutableDictionary.alloc().initWithDictionary_(pdfdoc.documentAttributes())
attrs[PDFDocumentTitleAttribute] = "THIS IS THE TITLE"
attrs[PDFDocumentAuthorAttribute] = "A. Author and B. Author"

pdfdoc.setDocumentAttributes_(attrs)
pdfdoc.writeToFile_("mynewfile.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tamás. Just one question, where can I find what the other attributes are? I'm trying to hard-code metadata from a .bib file with the PDFs and I don't know if there are any limits on what I can store.

Comment: Just look them up in the documentation of PDFKit on Apple's homepage; the list of constants you are looking for is here (sorry for the long link): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003873 . Look for the Constants section and "Document Attribute Keys" within it.

Comment: I've been a bit slow trying out this code - but I can't get it to run beyond the line <url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_("test.pdf")>. Is there anything version specific about <PDFDocument.alloc().initWithUrl_(url)>?

Comment: Exact error message: "pdfdoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithUrl_(url)
AttributeError: 'PDFDocument' object has no attribute 'initWithUrl_'"

Comment: Ermmm... I made a booboo when copying the source code from my Python terminal. It should be `initWithURL_` and not `initWithUrl_`. Note the capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER:  I'm utterly new to Python, but an old hand at PDF.

To avoid smashing all the existing attributes, you need to start `attrs` with `pdfDoc.documentAttributes`, not `{}`.  setDocumentAttributes is almost certainly an *overwrite* rather than a *merge* (given your output here).

Second, all the `PDFDocument*Attribute` constants are part of `PDFDocument`.  My Python ignorance is undoubtedly showing, but shouldn't you be referencing them as attributes rather than as bare variables?  Like this:

```
attrs[PDFDocument.PDFDocumentTitleAttribute] = "THIS IS THE TITLE"
```

That you can assign to PDFDocumentTitleAttribute leads me to believe it's not a constant.

If I'm right, your attrs will have tried to assign numerous values to a null key.  My Python is weak, so I don't know how you'd check that.  Examining `attrs` prior to calling `pdfDoc.setDocumentAttributes_()` should be revealing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mark. I'm just trying to understand the first part of your comment - should it be pdfDoc.documentAttributes = {} or pdfDoc.documentAttributes.attrs = {}?

Comment: attrs = pdfdoc.documentAttributes