# Changing a PDF author programmatically

Tags: python, pdf

In my office we have about 1000 PDFs that have arbitrary title and author information. My bosses had a spreadsheet created with the PDFs filename and an appropriate title and appropriate author information.

I would like to find a programmatic way to move the data from the Excel sheet to the PDF attributes?

My preferred language is Python so I looked for a Python library to do this, each library I looked at had the author and title fields as read-only.

If Python doesn't have a library that works I am okay using VBA, VB.NET, JavaScript... I will take this as an opportunity to learn a new language.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Some good answers over at http://askubuntu.com/questions/27381/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-from-command-line for doing it with CLI tools.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100405/writing-metadata-to-a-pdf-using-pyobjc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn java you can use the [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/metadata.html)

[Here](http://kickjava.com/src/org/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddMetadataFromDocInfo.java.htm) is an implementation example.

Answer (score -1):

Use Action Wizard in Acrobat X Pro.

Create New Action.

Setup *Start With*, and *Save To* step.

Set checkbox *Overwrite existing files*.

Select *Content*. Select *Add Document Description*.

Left mouse click in option. Uncheck *Autor* checkbox *Leave As Is* and enter new Autor name.

Press *Save* button, set name action **Your Action Name**.

Run Action:

*File*- *Action Wizard* - **Your Action Name**.

I test it - work).

Comment: Please note the word "programmatically" in the question. Manual steps using Acrobat X Pro aren't relevant ... this should be deleted.

Comment: @JimBalter In the question of the author, the task is considered not of a programmer, but rather of a system administrator. Such tasks are solved as quickly as possible in any way. Perhaps you want to complicate `this.info.author = <SetNewAuthor>` But why?) This question is for the `superuser`.
Javascript will be formally executed.

Comment: " the task is considered not of a programmer, but rather of a system administrator" -- No, again, it says "programmatically". Every word of the title, the question, the comments under the question, and the accepted answer are about programming. And no, this is not a question for the superuser -- there's a StackExchange for that, but this is StackOverflow, which is devoted to programming.