# Adding meta data when plotting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, plot, metadata

when I plot via [pdf()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html) in R, I would like to set the meta data for the PDF: title, author, keywords, subject. The default for the title seems to be "R Graphics Output".

How can I specify the meta data?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set the document's title by passing an appropriate `title` arg to the `pdf()` function. For other metadata, refer to this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647777/is-there-a-way-to-add-author-metadata-to-a-pdf-created-from-r) in which the usage of external tools (like `pdftk` or `exiftool`) is recommended, see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27381) at AskUbuntu.