# setting pdf report metadata

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to change the metadata of a report obtained in Rstudio with knitr.

I have tried the markdown way

```
---
title: "2014 Report"
author: "My Name"
---
```

and a second way

````
```{r}
opts_knit$set(header = "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"this is a description\">")
```
````

but in both cases I get errors in `eval`.

Can you help me or point me to the correct documentation?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible chunk of code?

Comment: The code is pretty much what you see... All is done in RStudio by the "Compile Notebook" function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add "author" metadata to a pdf created from R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647777/is-there-a-way-to-add-author-metadata-to-a-pdf-created-from-r)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I disagree, that question was for pdf graphics, here it's a report and the engine is completely different (latex).

Answer (score 1):

`opts_knit$set(header)` does not work for R Markdown (`*.Rmd`). It is for R HTML (`*.Rhtml`) only, which is rarely used by anyone. The `eval()` error was due to the fact that you did not load the **knitr** package. Please `library(knitr)` before you use any objects, including `opts_knit`, in this package.

To answer your real question, there are two approaches: see the **rmarkdown** documentation http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

- include a custom HTML header, and you can read the section "Includes"
- or if you want further customization, the section "Custom Templates" explained how to create your own Pandoc template (the default HTML template in this package is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/h/default.html))

Comment: Thanks Yihui, however the procedure looks complicated. (I have tried to modify the template but I still get errors.) I am switching from pdf to msword output, so I can change the metadata by hand!

Comment: @DarioLacan That sounds terrible... You will have to do this by hand over and over again when you update the R Markdown document. The procedure is not complicated if you take the first approach I mentioned. If you get errors, please post the error messages instead of only saying "I get errors", which will make everyone _guess_ what could be wrong. You can always edit your original question as answers come.