# Including meta data in an image

Tags: r

Is there any way to include meta data in an image file exported from R? Such as the title, description or keywords that appear in the 'picture properties' which can be viewed in software outside of R. What I'd really like to do is include the R file that generated the image in this meta data. There are no options in the standard jpeg or tiff export functions, and I couldn't see anything in the Cairo package.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24254259/489704) might be helpful.

Comment: The ExifTool worked, thanks. Although I could only view the meta data outside of R in Windows Photo Viewer and not in Microsoft Office or Photoshop, but that's a minor gripe.

Comment: You should be able to see the metadata using WindozeExplorer. "Luke, use the power of the Right-Click."